# typeahead.js and bootstrap 3 change source on close dropdown

Tags: bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

I have an input field in bootstrap 3 and I want to make it autocomplete with values from some local data, so I chose bootstrap-typeahead. The problem is that when the user chooses some value, I want to change the source of typeahead so that this value is no longer included in the available options. I have simplified a jsfiddle because the only thing that I can't do is change the source.

The following code doesn't work.

```
autocomplete.on('typeahead:closed', function( i, j) {
//change source
   autocomplete.data('typeahead').source = altdata.ttAdapter();
});
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/gtzoumis/rdC3Z/4/

There are some answers for previous versions but none of them work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer was to destroy the object and create it again...
thanks to this [link](http://tosbourn.com/2013/07/javascript/refreshing-local-data-with-typeahead-js/)

```
 autocomplete.typeahead('destroy');
    $('.autocomplete').typeahead(null, {
        name: "autocomplete",
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: altrepos.ttAdapter()
    });
```

Comment: Not the most elegant of solutions but at least it works!